# PHP file upload error: undefined index

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to my server or just open it and handle the contents but I get this strange error and I don't know why.

HTML form: http://pastebin.com/cSfMmvKF

php script: http://pastebin.com/fPzRVy5Y

If I try to test if the file is received I get a false response. Example:

```
if (isset($_FILES['epifile']))
    echo 'Is set';
```

This evaluates as false. I'm pretty sure everything is quite correct so I have no idea where the error comes from. Can you guys help?

Edit: I'm running this with XAMPP on my own PC. Could it be some setting that I need to enable within Apache?

Comment: Try `print_r($_FILES);` and see is there that index.

Comment: Take a look at [ask], then improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form must have an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, this works apparently. They did an amazing job not to mention it in every tutorial I read in the past 2 hours before comming here.